# Notification bar to be disable in android 4.4 permanently for my app

Tags: java, android, notifications

I need to disable the notification bar inside my app on android 4.4, this code is working for fist time disable the notification bar, second time when i dropdown i can view the notification. can i set notification bar disable in my activity for a while. please help me by any way.

Her is my code ....

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View. SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    int uiOption = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOption);      
    decorView.requestFocus();
    decorView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

this should be added before the setContentView();

and for hiding actionbar :

```
getActionBar().hide;
```

and if that dont work try this..

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using immersive full-screen mode, that was introduces in 4.4? Seems to me, it is what you need.
More details: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html